# how do i change the value that is passed by a method?

Tags: java

so i'm trying to increase the value of that is stored in getDay() by 1 but this method doesn't work. any advice? thanks

```
if(getDay()<1 || getDay()>31);
        {
        int temp = getDay();
        temp++;
        getDay() = temp;
        }
```

Comment: do you have a setDay(int day)?

Comment: Can you show us more of the class source code?

Comment: Are there getMonth() and getYear() methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the value returned by `getDay()` this way:

```
getDay() = temp;  <-- this won't work
```

Instead, if a `setDay()` method exists, then you could call that:

```
setDay(temp);
```

Or, you need to read the code for the `getDay()` method and figure out how to set the value in that code.

**Edit**

So, your code could look like this:

```
if(getDay()<1 || getDay()>31)
{
    int temp = getDay();
    temp++;
    setDay(temp);
}
```

Or...

```
if(getDay()<1 || getDay()>31)
{
    int temp = getDay();
    setDay(++temp);
}
```

Comment: we cannot touch the getday method so i can't put the temp within parameter. there is a setter that looks like this public IncDate(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        super(month, day, year);
    }
we also cannot make any changes to this.

Comment: You shouldn't be touching the `getDay()` method. Its purpose is to `get` the `day`. If there is a `setDay()` method, you should try using it and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: so how can i set the variables using the increment method?

Answer (score 2):

you are using

```
getDay() = temp;
```

but that means calling the method and setting the returned value to temp ...or so.

try set the initial value to temp which getDay() handles back.
You need to find the value being told by getDay() in the class containing  that value and access it directly. sorry for my engl

example:
your method:

```
public int getDay(){return day;}
```

set method:

```
public void setDay(int dayPassed){
day= dayPassed;
```

}

in your example:

```
if(getDay()<1 || getDay()>31);
    {
    int temp = getDay();
    temp++;
    setDay(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't increase the return value of a function by just assigning a value to it. I think you will need to learn more on functions/methods and how they work.